# HTML5 video for iPhone / iPad. How to detect connection speed?

Tags: html, ios, video-streaming

I need to stream a video in Safari for iPhone/iPad with the best possible quality.

I created 2 video files: one in low-quality for slow 3G speed, one in hi-quality for WiFi broadband streaming. I noticed that some apps (YouTube for example) are able to detect if the mobile device is running by 3G or WiFi, and so select a small sized video rather than an hi-quality video.

Now that is my DOM / Javascript code, the *$v* value is replaced by *PHP* and contains the video filename:

```
<video id="thevideo" src="streaming/video_<?=$v ?>.m4v" width="600" height="360" width="640" height="360" preload="preload" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
flowplayer/video<?=$v ?>.m4v
</video>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var myvideo = document.getElementById("thevideo");

myvideo.load();
myvideo.play();
</script>
```

Can I write something in Javascript / Webkit that is able to detect the connection mode?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I am assuming this will be in your own application:

You could use Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to determine the connection type in your application before sending the UIWebView's request. You can modify the request's URL by adding a query:

```
//determine the connection type via Reachability

myURLString = [myURLString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?conntype=%@", *connTypeString]];

//then send the request for the page.
```

Then, parse the URL query in PHP to determine the video URL that should be used.

- If not, you would need to test the connection speed via a third-party Javascript or PHP script.

Example: http://jan.moesen.nu/code/php/speedtest/index.php?numKB=512

Answer (score 3):

You will have to load some sort of document to test your connection speed.

an example -- http://alexle.net/archives/257