# Detecting WIFI connectivity in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, mobile-safari

Is it possible to detect, through Javascript, whether the user is connected to a WIFI or high speed connection as opposed to a slow one? I'm trying to use something like that to load a compressed version of a video if the user is on a slow connection.

Like:

`if (onwifi) {
//heavy video
} else { //light video}`

Comment: This is more of a question about detecting connection speed and is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185266/html5-video-for-iphone-ipad-how-to-detect-connection-speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can gauge the connection speed.

Create a new `Date` object, then use the DOM to download an image of a fixed size, with a random number appended on the end so the client doesn't cache it. The image's `onload` event should subtract the time before the image was downloaded from the current time, therefore giving you the number of milliseconds it took to download.

```
var imageurl='http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png';
var image=document.createElement('image');
image.src=imageurl+'?'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
document.body.appendChild(image);
var imagetook=0;
var date=new Date();
image.onload=function(){
    imagetook=getMilliseconds();
    startmovie();
}
```