# To check if browser run using 3G or Wifi in windows desktop

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to find if the user using 3G or wifi or anyother bandwidth in windows desktop ...

if ound some links for detecting on iphone/ipad mobile browsers using this link [HTML5 video for iPhone / iPad. How to detect connection speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185266/html5-video-for-iphone-ipad-how-to-detect-connection-speed)

but is it possible for desktop windows bandwidth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459029/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-user-is-on-a-wifi-connection-with-php-or-javascrip

Comment: is this answer is correct , we can't detect which brandwidth we are using ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Connection.bandwidth

Comment: @dandavis they show its supported only for firefox but if they use other browsers i can't detect it. i want if we detect in all broswers which one the users view.

Comment: you can always time how long it takes to download a 100kb file...